# Game Object is Instantiating on same position

Tags: c#, unity, gameobject

I am working on a small project . But now I have come across a problem . The problem is the prefab is instantiating on the same position .

I want to instantiate a box end to end . The basic set up is as follows : -
[image]

[image]

Image 3 :- Please see the comment below

Box game object has a parent empty object (Start_point) , and a child empty object (end point) . Those marks the Start and End of that game object .

The game a empty game object (Tile_Gen) which has a C# script as follows :-

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tile_Gen : MonoBehaviour 
{

   public GameObject G_O_01 ;

   public GameObject Current_Tile ;

   public Vector3 Start_Position_Of_Path ;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Start_Position_Of_Path = Current_Tile.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position;
    Instantiate(Current_Tile , Start_Position_Of_Path , Quaternion.identity);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    Path_Generator ();
}

public void Path_Generator()
{
    Instantiate(G_O_01 , Start_Position_Of_Path , Quaternion.identity);
// End of tile position = start tile position
    Start_Position_Of_Path = G_O_01.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position;   
    print (Start_Position_Of_Path);
}
}
```

Here G_O_01 is Start_point prefab , Current_Tile is Start_point .

But this is not instantiating as I wanted . This instantiates all the object at one place .

But I want something like one behind the another , like this :-

Image 4 :- Please see the comments below

So Please help me to figure it out .

Regards NB :)

Comment: Image 3 :- http://s10.postimg.org/a2cqtappl/image.png

Comment: Image 4 :- http://s9.postimg.org/ctwm25m5b/image.png

Answer (score 1):

You'r approach is rather strange, but stick with it an learn it's faults / strengths because creating it your way is a great way to learn. Below is the same concept just cleaned up a bit. Remember that in your setup, the box object has to be offset so the left side of the box is at the same position as its parent. This can be done with sprites setting the pivot to the right side, or by offsetting the childs transform.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Prefab;

    private GameObject _previousTile;
    private Vector3 _nextStartPosition;

    void Update()
    {
        PathGenerator();
    }

    private void PathGenerator()
    {
        _previousTile = Instantiate(Prefab, GetNextStartPosition(), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

    private Vector3 GetNextStartPosition()
    {
        if(_previousTile == null)
            return Vector3.zero;

        var BoxObject = _previousTile.transform.GetChild(0);
        if(BoxObject == null)
            return Vector3.zero;

        var endOfLastTile = BoxObject.GetChild(0);
        if(endOfLastTile == null)
            return  Vector3.zero;

        return endOfLastTile.position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but little late. I have already figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you Instantiate them in the same position:

```
Instantiate(G_O_01 , Start_Position_Of_Path , Quaternion.identity);
Start_Position_Of_Path = G_O_01.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position;
```

You could try something like this in your Start ():

```
float n = 5.0f;
Vector3 dist = ((endPoint - startPoint)/n);
for( int i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
    Instantiate(G_O_01 , startPoint + dist*i , Quaternion.identity);
}
```

This code will Instantiate n+1 G_O_01 objects on straight line between endPoint and startPoint ( including both points ).

Edit:

Why your code spawns them in one position?

In short. You place object in position `Start_Position_Of_Path`. Then you set `Start_Position_Of_Path` to this object's position ( which is of course equal to `Start_Position_Of_Path` ), and spawn next object in `Start_Position_Of_Path`, etc. etc.

Comment: So can you tell me where I went wrong ? Why this public void Path_Generator()
{
    Instantiate(G_O_01 , Start_Position_Of_Path , Quaternion.identity);
// End of tile position = start tile position
    Start_Position_Of_Path = G_O_01.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position;   
    print (Start_Position_Of_Path);
} is generating at same position . According to that I have accessed End position of last object and assign it to the new starting position . But why It is generating at same point .

Comment: Regards NB | :--)

Comment: @NicolusBuck updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are giving same point every time. Second bad practice is you are calling your generator method in `Update`.

Well, if you want to spawn platforms in linear path then you adopt ambiguous way. You made an empty `parent`, then `child` (platform) then then again child `gameObject` for End Point. It would bevery confusing because of global and localPositions.

Here is a simpler way to achieve your goal.

- Delete `parent` and `child` and make prefab of only box.

Now what your script do,

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tile_Gen : MonoBehaviour 
{

   public GameObject G_O_01 ;

   GameObject _lastTile;
   float _tileGap = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        _lastTile = Instantiate(G_O_01) as GameObject;
        _tileGap = _lastTile.transform.localScale.x/2.0f;

        // Creating 20 tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            Path_Generator ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    // A general method, whenever you call it, it will spawn tile next to previous one.

    public void Path_Generator()
    {
        _lastTile = Instantiate(G_O_01 , new Vector3(_lastTile.transform.position.x + _tileGap ,_lastTile.transform.position.y,_lastTile.transform.position.z) , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }

}
```

Now set you block in editor to very start (at very left) then make prefab or apply changes. After that drop your `GameObject` to this script. **Because** this script is spawning tiles from left to right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So can you tell me where I went wrong ? Why this public void Path_Generator() { Instantiate(G_O_01 , Start_Position_Of_Path , Quaternion.identity); // End of tile position = start tile position Start_Position_Of_Path = G_O_01.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).position; print (Start_Position_Of_Path); } is generating at same position . According to that I have accessed End position of last object and assign it to the new starting position . But why It is generating at same point ? Regards NB :-)

Comment: I don't know your logic, but I'd tell you what is obvious. Because you are accessing your `G_O_01` every time to update your `Start_Position_Of_Path`. Keep in mind that `Instantiate(G_O_01)` will make no impact on `G_O_01`, as `Instantiate` will create and return a copy of that object. Here `G_O_01` is like a blue print.

Comment: Ok , Thanks for the reply . Finally figured it out where I went wrong :)

Comment: Good to listen that :)

Comment: BTW you can use the suggested solution as it is more easy. I think :)

Comment: For reference you can have a look at [this link](http://www.hamzahasan.com/how-to-make-zig-zag-in-unity/) :)

Comment: Is this tutorials from you :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-8UAppL6JY

Comment: I didn't make any video tut yet :)